# How to send a Discord message to a channel using JS & Chrome Console?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, console, discord

How to send a Discord message to a discord channel using JS & Chrome Console without using Discord API?

It seems that it is impossible...

Comment: Hey @nahha I'd like to update you, I've just tried Hurl.it to make the same request using the same parameters from a message I sent earlier changing the "Content-Length" header to the JSON length the message I sent and it worked!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tKz6A You just need to create a request with those headers you can see on the hurl.it request and you can do it.

Comment: I've added another image to the imgur album: https://i.imgur.com/8nFbKkw.png which shows the minimal needed parameters so you can send a POST request and make it work. The only problem is the Authorization parameter, but by sending a message once manually, you can copy it from the Network tab on the XHR request. The content obviously needs to be a JSON type string with "content", "nonce" and "tts" parameters which I don't really know what they mean, with only the "content" parameter, the message will still send correctly.

Comment: Why don't you post an answer insteadf of comment? These are getting deleted appearently

Comment: I deleted my answer because it wasn't fully correct and I can't answer a way to do it effectively. I can just tell you what parameters you need, but I couldn't get insight on how to get them programmatically.

Comment: How strict is the requirement to not use the Discord API? Would using a Discord bot with an exposed endpoint that interfaces with the API on your behalf be a sufficient solution?

Comment: It would be preferred that the solution only use the Chrome developer console or a form of JavaScript bookmarklet if the console is still having issues on Discord.

Answer (score 14):

Open discord console : ctrl + shift + i (doesn't work? see edit below)

Then go into the network tab.

Now we need to sniff a message, so type a message in discord and send it.

Then in the console network tab right click the request named "messages", and pick "Copy as fetch".

Then go to the "Console" tab. Paste the request.

Edit this request to remove the "noonce" field.

And also there, edit the "content" field with your message.

When you press enter it should send it.

**EDIT**

As of today, discord team disabled the console by default.

There are 2 options to use it :

- either open discord in your web browser and use F12 to open the console
- or set "DANGEROUS_ENABLE_DEVTOOLS_ONLY_ENABLE_IF_YOU_KNOW_WHAT_YOURE_DOING": to true in %appdata%/discord/settings.json

Comment: Just to clarify - you can find the "`nonce`" field located after `body` and `content`. Anyways, great answer!

Comment: Awesome!!!. Thank You for making the Internet one of the best thing in the world...

Comment: Assuming that's a timed access token, how do I get a new one?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I think I found the answer you were looking for. Many of the headers that you may have thought to use are unnecessary for this to work.

The headers that matter for most everything:

> **authorization:** TOKEN
>
> **accept:** "/"
>
> **authority:** discordapp.com

When sending a message, you must also specify the content-type:

> **content-type:** application/json

Therefore, you can easily construct a JavaScript POST request to send a discord message to a channel using the following code or similar:

```
message = "Hi!";

token = "TOKEN";

channel_id = "CHANNEL ID";

channel_url = `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/${channel_id}/messages`

request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.withCredentials = true;
request.open("POST", channel_url);
request.setRequestHeader("authorization", token);
request.setRequestHeader("accept", "/");
request.setRequestHeader("authority", "discordapp.com");
request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.send(JSON.stringify({ content: message }));
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Keep in mind the domain is discord.com and not disordapp.com

Comment: now v8. so `https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/${channel_id}/messages`

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer written by MiGu3X.

This is a sample way of sending data:

[image].

Comment: That's a good example, but the best one would be this https://i.imgur.com/8nFbKkw.png image since it has the required parameters, apparently.