# Sending a message to Discord channel via POST request results in code 401

Tags: api, post, google-chrome-extension, discord, http-status-code-401

I was searching for the easiest way to send a message to Discord channel from Chrome extension. 
I have a Discord app and corresponding bot registered on Discord Developer Portal. I have bot token there. 
Found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47964302/how-to-send-a-discord-message-to-a-channel-using-js-chrome-console). Tried the code Tobyhn suggested and ended up with this:

```
var token = "my bot token here";
var channel_id = "my channel id here";
var channel_url = `https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/${channel_id}/messages`

request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.withCredentials = true;
request.open("POST", channel_url);
request.setRequestHeader("authorization", token);
request.setRequestHeader("accept", "/");
request.setRequestHeader("authority", "discord.com");
request.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");

request.send(JSON.stringify({ content: message }));
```

Code is just placed right in background script. 
Chrome is run with flags --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~\chromeTemp" to avoid CORS checks. 
Also I'm absolutely sure that bot is given Administrator privileges on Discord server that channel is at, so writing a message must be possible.
However, upon execution server responds with code 401:

```
code: 0 
message: "401: Unauthorized"
```

I also tried to send the same request from Yet Another Rest Client and result was the same.

**How can I change the request for it to successfully authorize and send the message?**

To provide additional context: the very same bot successfully sends messages to various channels on the same server when I use it with help of discord.js library.
I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020723/discord-post-message-to-channel-using-curl-php) thread, but the solution there seems not to be found and nothing said there seems to be applicable to my situation.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Token Type

Example Bot Token Authorization Header
`Authorization: Bot MTk4NjIyNDgzNDcxOTI1MjQ4.Cl2FMQ.ZnCjm1XVW7vRze4b7Cq4se7kKWs`

Example Bearer Token Authorization Header
`Authorization: Bearer CZhtkLDpNYXgPH9Ml6shqh2OwykChw`

So Change `request.setRequestHeader("authorization", token);`
with `request.setRequestHeader("authorization",` Bot ${token}`);` if you are using bot token

https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference

No, they are not real tokens, I get them from their documentation.